# PHP MVC - Why is my request/router always going to home controller?

Tags: php, url-routing, http-get

I've tried many fixes but for some reason my request and routing mechanisms in my framework aren't working properly. It's a multi-language site (en/fr) and I use mod_rewrite to get the language, class, method and an optional argument. My request.php sets the controller to languageController if the language isn't set, and it works (successfully echo "language" in controller). But, if the language is set, the controller that always ends up displaying is homeController despite that the uri is /en/about. I have no idea why this is happening and it's really frustrating me. Here's the problem code, help is appreciated.

Note: I haven't used namespaces as it is a small website that I just want to get up and running and there's no real need, although I plan to edit it to use namespaces in the future simply for the leaning.

relevant parts of index.php

```
//analyze request
$request = new Request($_GET); //breaks up the uri into an array

//routing
$router = new Router($request); //stores the requested uri in the router
$router->route(); //sets the proper route

//instancialize and execute the controller
$class = $router->getController();
$method = $router->getMethod();
$controller = new $class;
$controller->$method();
```

Request.php

```
class Request {
    private $request;
    public function __construct($uri) {
        $this->request = $uri;
        //if the language isn't selected
        if($this->request['language']=="") {
            $this->request['language'] = "language";
            $this->request['class'] = "language";
            $this->request['method'] = "index";
        }
        //else if the controller is not selected
        else if($this->request['controller']=="") {
            $this->request['class'] = "home";
            $this->request['method'] = "index";
        }

        //stores the requested method
        else if($this->request['method']=="") {
            $this->request['method'] = "index";
        }
        //stores a value of false if there is no argument in the uri
        if($this->request['arg']=="") {
            $this->request['arg'] = false;
        }
    }
    public function getLanguage() {
        return $this->request['language'];
    }   
    public function getClass() {
        return $this->request['class'];
    }   
    public function getMethod() {
        return $this->request['method'];
    }
    public function getArgument() {
        return $this->request['arg'];
    }
}
```

Router.php

```
class Router {
    private $language;
    private $controller;
    private $view;
    private $method;
    private $arg;
    public function __construct(Request $request) { //given an instance of request, store it in local variables
        $this->language = $request->getLanguage();
        $this->controller = $request->getClass() . 'Controller';
        $this->view = $request->getClass() . 'View';
        $this->method = $request->getMethod();
        $this->arg = $request->getArgument();
    }
    public function route() { //put the requested uri into forms we can deal with
        if($this->language == "fr") { //compare it against url translation chart
            //run all uri values through a chart that translates them from french to english if it finds a match
        }
        else { //it must be english

        }
    }
    public function getLanguage() {
        return $this->language;
    }   
    public function getController() {
        return $this->controller;
    }   
    public function getView() {
        return $this->view;
    }
    public function getMethod() {
        return $this->method;
    }
    public function getArgument() {
        return $this->arg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check what are the key's for the `$_GET` values? And are you sure that the key is `"controller"` and not `"class"`? Do a `var_dump( $_GET );` at some point. And you might consider switching to `$request->getParameter($name)` for your request API, instead of having 4+ getters, that do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Also, please don't put computation in the constructors. It makes harder for you to debug your own code and quite impossible to unit-test it.

Comment: I checked the key's for $_GET and they work (language, class, method, arg). I switched to a $request->getKey($key) for my request API as suggested. You're right, it seems neater and easier to test, thank you very much for the help, I'll do some more testing and let you know the result.

Comment: Found the problem. In my .htaccess there used to be a controller parameter that I changed to class, because the controller and view have a 1:1 relationship, I thought class would be a more appropriate name. In my request.php I forgot to change one of the parameters from controller to class. Thank you very much teresko, I think I would have given up a few times without your help!